# Counting parameters of object constructor (external method)

Tags: php, class, autoload

I write a code that autoload classes, and I encountered a problem which I think is because of weakness implementation/design type. What I want to do is to count default parameters of an object (external).
I can count the number of passed arguments to constructor, but I will need to check that inside object constructor and that method does not help me.

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
// This is simple
function test($arg1,$arg2,$arg3) {return func_num_args();}
// How can I count like this?
class load
{
    public function __construct($id="",$path="") {}
}
$l = new load();
// How to count object default parameters count(object($l)), I need answer to be 2`
```

**MY CODE WHERE I NEED TO USE THIS METHOD:**

**[File: global_cfg.php]**

```
<?php
// File: global_cfg.php
define(ROOT, __DIR__);    // Root directory
define(DEBUG, true);      // Set debugging state ON or OFF
define(MODE, "producer"); // If debug mode is ON: producer, publisher, tester

/*
 * PATH CONFIGURATIONS:
 */

define(DS, "/");
define(LIB, "library");        

/*
 * SIGN AUTOLOAD CLASSES:
 * Setting class sign to true value, the autoloader will create automatically
 * an instance of the class lowercase type.
 */

$signClasses = Array
(
    "Ralor"    => false,
    "NaNExist" => true,
    "Message"  => array(MODE),
    "Debug"    => DEBUG,
    "Resource" => true,
    "View"     => true
);
```

**[File: autoload_classes.php]**

```
<?php
// File: autoload_classes.php
require_once("global_cfg.php");
print "<b>Loaded classes:</b> <br>";
function __autoloadClasses($list, $suffix="class", $extension="php")
{
    $path="";
    foreach($list as $fileName => $classInstance)
    {
        $path = ROOT.DS.LIB.DS.$fileName.".".$suffix.".".$extension; 
        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            print "Signed class ".$fileName." does not exist!<br>";
            continue;
    }
        require_once($path);
        print $path;
        if($classInstance)
        {
            $GLOBALS[strtolower($fileName)] = new $fileName();
            // ??? todo: counting default object parameters 
            $count = count(get_object_vars($GLOBALS[strtolower($fileName)]));
            if(is_array($classInstance))
            {
                if($count<count($classInstance))
                {
                    print "Arguments passed to object exceeds the limit";
                }
                else if($count>count($classInstance))
                {
                    print "Insuficient arguments passed to the object!";
                }
                else
                {
                    // todo: create object and pass parameters
                    $GLOBALS[strtolower($fileName)] = new $fileName(/*$arg1 .. $argn*/);    
                }
            }
            print $count." -> Class was instantiated!<br>";
            continue;
        }
        print "<br>";
    }
}__autoloadClasses($signClasses);
```

After this problem I can finish my bootstrap.

Comment: Look up reflection Class

Comment: Thanks for post, reflection is the way I think I will read the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php). For example.

```
class load
    {

    public function __construct($id = "", $path = "")
        {

        }

    }

function getNumberOfParameters($class_name)
    {
    $class_reflection = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    $constructor = $class_reflection->getConstructor();
    if ($constructor === null)
        return 0;
    else
        return $constructor->getNumberOfParameters();
    }

var_dump(getNumberOfParameters('load'));
```

Comment: Yes works but how I can count if object is not instantiated? For example I want to create object *before I read number of arguments that accepts.